# Flask errorhandler isn't called for view that returns 404

Tags: python, flask

With the following functions, I'd expect the error handler to get called when the view returns 404. But it does not trigger. Why doesn't a 404 error handler get called when a view returns 404?

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def error(e):
    return render_template('error.html'), 404


@app.route('/error/')
def error_test():
    return '', 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handlers handle errors. If you just `return '',404` then your function has finished normally, it just returned an 404 HTTP code. There were no errors, so error handler is not called.

In python we report errors with exceptions. If something goes wrong, you throw it. Flask has special base exception class [HTTPException](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException). If you throw it, then appropriate error handler would be used to render it. See [HTTPException documentation](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException) for examples. There is also a bunch of predefined exceptions and in your case you need to throw [NotFound](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound).

Answer (score 4):

You aren't triggering the error. You can use `abort` for that.

```
from flask import abort

@app.route('/error/')
def error_test():
    abort(404)
```